Best material to use under drywall returns?
Thoughts between wood or metal, or both, for jamb extensions on replacement windows with drywall returns?
Is there any risk to going with wood? Is it overkill to have metal on top of the wood jamb extensions? Top pic is original metal jamb under drywall. Bottom pic is the original drywall return.



Wood or metal is fine, wood is probably stronger, but the metal is probably easier - unless you're a carpenter - you do you.
